# Getting MAC from IP returns IP outside of subnet

Tags: powershell, ip, mac-address, scanning

```
function Get-MacAddress {
    param( [string]$device= $( throw "Please specify device" ) )
    if ( $device | ? { $_ -match "[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]" } )
    {
      #"Searching by IP Address"
      $ip = $device
    } else {
        #"Searching by Host Name"
        $ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($device).AddressList[0].IpAddressToString
    }
    arp -d; # purge arp cache
    $ping = ( new-object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ).Send($ip);
    $mac = arp -a;
    if($ping)
    {
        ( $mac | ? { $_ -match $ip } ) -match "([0-9A-F]{2}([:-][0-9A-F]{2}){5})" | out-null;
        if ( $matches ) {
            $matches[0];
        } else {
            "Not Found"
        }
    }
}

Get-MacAddress(192.168.2.231);
```

If I run that I get the following:

```
192.168.56.1
```

I am not sure how I am getting that IP and not a MAC.

What I need to do is get the MAC of an IP address so when I can scan for IPs I can pull out specific IPs that have a certain MAC.

These are not Windows machines but other random devices on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Silly me. I was passing incorrectly.

```
$device = "192.168.2.231";
Get-MacAddress($device);
```